# C++: How to ignore ReadFile() if there is no new data from the serial port?

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port, readfile

I am working on a C++ program which can read from a serial port and write to a serial port. I have a problem at reading the data. If there is no new data, `ReadFile()` is waiting until it receive new data.

My code to read the data:

```
while (!_kbhit())
    {
        if (!_kbhit())
        {
            if (ReadFile(hSerial, &c, 1, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
            {
                cout << c;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I check if there is no new data and skip the `ReadFile()` line?

**EDIT:**

I was finally able to fix it.
I changed my ReadFunction to this:

```
do
{
    if (ReadFile(hSerial, &c, 1, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
    {
        if (isascii(c))
        {
            cout << c;
        }
    }
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        key = _getch();
    }
} while (key != 27);
```

And I added Timeouts like this:

```
serialHandle = CreateFile(LcomPort, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;  

    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
    SetCommTimeouts(serialHandle, &timeouts);

// Call function to Read
...
```

Comment: Use PeekNamedPipe()

Comment: you need open file in asynchronous mode (with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag )

Comment: @RbMm I open the file with serialHandle = CreateFile(LcomPort, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0); . Where sould I add FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED?

Comment: @User987123 - `CreateFile(LcomPort, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0)`

Comment: @RbMm With this solution I can easily stop reading from the port but when there is new data it isn't showing it at all.

Comment: @User987123 - because you need rewrite your code for asynchronous programming. you need say for example bind iocp to your file and handle result in callbacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there is no new data, `ReadFile()` is waiting until it receive new data.

You can use [`SetCommTimeouts()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363437.aspx) to configure a reading timeout so `ReadFile()` will exit if no data arrives within the timeout interval.

Comment: After I open the file I added this:
                `COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
  timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
  timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
  timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1;`
But it is still not working. My ReadFile Function:

`do
 {
  if (ReadFile(hSerial, &c, 1, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
  {
   cout << c;
  }
  if (_kbhit())
  {
   key = _getch();
  }
 } while (key != 27);`

What am I missing?

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

Try [ReadFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of

It is asynchronous function

Comment: `It is asynchronous function` - only in case when file handle created with the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag. but in this case `ReadFile` also act asynchronous. simply replace `ReadFile` to `ReadFileEx` nothing change. use this function have sense only if you plan use apc CompletionRoutine